# SSRS - parameter value change is not running my report again

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with two params that are datetime, @startdate and @enddate.

I have set them up under "advanced settings" to "Automatically determine when to refresh" (also tried "Always refresh") for both of the parameters.

I deployed my report and ran it. Changed the date and it appears the report fires a postback (screen flashes and browser indicates activity bottom left corner) but I end up with a blank screen (I still have my breadcrumb up top but everything below is blank). If I hit the "view report" button on the end of the header area it will run it again but my intention is to re-run the report when either parameter changes.

Not sure what I did wrong. I'm using SSRS 2008 and this was something I was able to do in the past versions of SSRS.

Comment: I don't suppose you ever solved this, did you? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: I did not find a solution

Answer (score -1):

If you hard code a default parameter value, like 1/1/2000, it doesn’t think it needs to refresh all the way (it gives you a blank report though!).  The solution is to point it to a query (dataset) that selects a date valued at 1/1/2000.  And I think for multiple parameters, you have to set all default values this way. Pathetic for sure.

Comment: Thanks for commenting on my issue. In the case of my StartDate param the default value is an expression of =Today().  For the EndDate my expression is =DateAdd("d",1, Today()). I have to do that because I want to see entries that fall in the current day and selecting by timestamp ranges doesn't seem to return everything.  So your saying that if I choose "get values from a query" instead and make another dataset that it should work? I'll test it out and report back. Seems odd for sure.

Comment: Ok well I finally had time to try your suggestion iejg. I set both my parameters in the report to always refresh. I created two datasets and wrote a query for each so they would have the proper value. My report still runs, but it does not auto refresh. I still have to click the button. Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1):

you need to deploy your report, once before you pass the parameters and once after you pass the parameters. that fixes the issue for me

Comment: You need to redeploy your report after changing the parameter values? O_o I don't get it...

Comment: This answer makes no sense. Parameter values are set at run time. Redploying the report will require it to be re-run, at which point any parameter values will return to their defaults. Maybe a word other than "deploy" was meant here, but I can't think what it should have been.